# What is the right way to use Date and Calendar in Java?

Tags: java, calendar

I'm trying to run a simple code that simulates a system for managing some cinema.

I have a Movie class, to which I want to add a Date.
(The Movie is part of a Cinema class that holds a Movies' array)
The user, when inserting new data to the cinema, supposed to enter - besides the 'name' and 'rating' of the movie - a date and time.
What would be the right way to set the date?

Should I create a new Calendar object to each and every Movie object and use it to set the date and time for every Movie?
Or should there be **one** Calendar object in Cinema that all Movie objects use to update the date and time (according to user input of course)?

Comment: How do users input the date? console? desktop UI? Web UI? Mobile? ...

Comment: Ideally, abandon Date and Calendar entirely and use Joda Time instead... It's a much better date/time API...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If entering date trough console then it is most likely saved as a single String. You have to define a format in which the date is entered. Use that format with a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to create a Date object out of it.

Something like this should do it:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
System.out.println("Please enter a date (" + dateFormat + "): ");
String dateString = sc.next();
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).parse(dateString);
System.out.println(date.toString());
sc.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by A4L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20785062/642706) is correct. But as Jon Skeet commented, you really should use Joda-Time. The java.util.Date/Calendar classes are notoriously bad, and are being supplanted in Java 8 by the java.time.* classes whose design is inspired by Joda-Time.

Be aware that unlike java.util.Date, a [org.joda.time.DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) knows its time zone.

Here's the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) version of A4L's example code.

You can choose or define other [formats for parsing](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). I went with the standard [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
DateTimeFormatter parser = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser();
// A good practice is to always specify a time zone rather than depend on default.
parser = parser.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/New_York" ) );
System.out.println("Please enter a date (" + "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ" + "): ");
String dateString = sc.next();
DateTime dateTime = null;
try {
    dateTime = parser.parseDateTime(dateString);
    System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime.toString() );
} catch ( IllegalArgumentException e ) {
    // e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println( "The date you entered cannot be parsed." );
}
sc.close();
```

When run…

```
Please enter a date (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ): 
2013-12-13T23:45
dateTime: 2013-12-13T23:45:00.000-05:00
```

Comment: +1 for ponting to joda and java8 - The `System.out` should be inside the `try` block though, otherwise it's a NPE if parsing fails ;-)

Comment: @A4L Thanks for System.out critique. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Date is for holding a specific instant in time value. Calendar is for date / time manipulation such as getting day of weeek etc

Answer (score 0):

If you use a single instance of Calendar then every movie will have the same date and time.  I don't think this is probably what you want, so you should go with a different one for each movie.